# how do I replace numbers using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I am using C# regex library to do some text find and replace.

I would like to change the following:

1 -> one

11 -> one one

123 -> one two three

for example, here's my code to replace ampersand:

```
        string pattern = "[&]";
        string replacement = " and ";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
        string result = rgx.Replace(text, replacement);
```

**Edit**
I found some great examples of .NET RegEx on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kweb790z.aspx

Comment: hmm. why not?  One reason is that it is one of the technical requirements. +1 if you give a good reason why regex is not a good solution here.  But the solution still gets the check..

Comment: You could use a regex to find or validate that you have a sequence of digits. But replacing each digit with its english name is much easier to do with plain old string manipulation functions.

Comment: Good explanation, but unfortunately I still have a technical requirement to do it this way.  Also this is a good exercise for me to learn more about regex.

Comment: No its not (apart from the validation/search part). Using a hammer to set a screw is not a good exercise for learning how to use a hammer (or a screw).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're specifically asking for a regex, you could do something like this

```
var digits = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
   { "0", "zero" },
   { "1", "one" },
   { "2", "two" },
   { "3", "three" },
   { "4", "four" },
   { "5", "five" },
   { "6", "six" },
   { "7", "seven" },
   { "8", "eight" },
   { "9", "nine" }
};

var text = "this is a text with some numbers like 123 and 456";

text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\d", x => digits[x.Value]);
```

which will give you

```
this is a text with some numbers like onetwothree and fourfivesix
```